# mpirun actual number of processors used

Tags: mpi

I am starting programming on an OpenMPI managed cluster.
I use the following command to run my executable:

```
mpirun -np 32 file
```

Now what I understand is that 32 specifies the number of processes that should be created. They may be created on the same processor. Am I right?

I am noticing increasing time for execution with increase in the number of processes. Could the above be a reason for this?

How do I find out the execution and scheduling policy of the cluster?

Is it correct to assume that typically the cluster I am working on will have many processes running on each node just as they run on my PC.

Comment: Can you post some (process count, execution time) pairs that we can look at to see exactly how execution time is related to process count?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your job management system (which is ?) to allocate 1 MPI process per core.  But that is a configuration matter and your cluster may not be configured as I expect.  Can you see what processes are running on the various cores of your cluster at run time ?

There are many explanations for increasing execution time with increasing numbers of processes, several good ones which include the possibility of one-process-per-core.  But multiple processes per core is a potential explanation.

You find out about the policies of your cluster by asking the cluster administrator.

No, I think it is atypical for cluster processors (or cores) to execute multiple MPI processes simultaneously.

Comment: I'll just add that if you are running that job interactively on some development node, then the processes are probably running all on one node (so if it's got 8 cores, you're running 4 procs per core).  If on the other hand you are executing that line as part of a job submission script, then as Mark says above, absent some configuration issues or misunderstandings, you're probably running one proc per core.